# Plotly: How to initiate 'x unified' hovermode?

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to replicate the example with `fig.update_layout(hovermode="x unified")` [here](https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/#unified-hovermode).

But what should look like this:

[image]

... ends up like this:

[image]

... using the same code:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent=='Oceania'")

fig = px.line(df, x="year", y="lifeExp", color="country", title="layout.hovermode='x unified'")
fig.update_traces(mode="markers+lines", hovertemplate=None)
fig.update_layout(hovermode="x unified")

fig.show()
```

An obvious answer could be that this functionality has been removed for newer versions of plotly, or that I'm running an old version. But I don't think so. I'm on `'4.6.0'`, and the source https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/#hover-labels does not indicate in any way that the example is from an older plotly version.

Comment: Hi vestland, I had the same problem and I fixed installing `jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-plotly` new version (which is 4.6.0 as well). See [issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2361#issuecomment-609783804)

Comment: @rpanai What may very well have been the issue. But having run your suggestion, jupyterlab only launches a blank page. Any suggestions? I also ran `jupyter lab build`.

Comment: What's your lav version? There are incompatibilies between 1.x and 2.x

Comment: @rpanai 2.x But that doesn't matter much now anyway. I finally found a good excuse to rip out everything and build my entire ecosystem from scratch. I've been running both `conda` and `pip` installs with mixed luck. My main problem is that I'm behind a pretty solid firewall and that often raises SSL issues. But the worst thing is with JupyterLab, plotly, node.js and chocolatey. I'm considering moving to VSCode with JupyterLab only on the side. I see you've provided lots of good plotly posts. If you'd like to discuss everything plotly, JupyterLab, VSCode or Spyder then let me know.

Comment: Feel free to contact me via Linkedin.

Comment: @rpanai Would you consider writing your suggestion up as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I opened an [issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2361#issue-595092899). In order to fix it you need to install the latest version (which is now, conveniently, having the same version numnber as plotly itself.) of the `jupyterlab-plotly` labextension with

```sh
jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-plotly
```

Keep in mind that this extension works with jupyter-lab 2+ only. A problem you could face is that at the moment is that the current version of `jupyterlab-dash` extension is not compatible with jupyter-lab 2+ see [issue](https://github.com/plotly/jupyterlab-dash/issues/37#issue-575097026).